# LLVM. Add function attributes info

Tags: ubuntu, llvm

With LLVM 3.4  I create a function with attributes:
`attributes #0 = { nounwind uwtable }` . It seems not bad, but clang++ writes much more information in same function:

`attributes #0 = { nounwind uwtable "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf"="true" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "ssp-buffer-size"="8" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }`

**How it is possible to add this information to attributes?** `llc -march=cpp` does not give the answer. 
Some google search led me to `llvm::TargetOptions`, but what to do with this class, it does not tell. What a shame.

*LLVM 3.4, Ubuntu 13.04 x64*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are target-dependent attributes. You can create those in a very similar way to creating target-independent ones, e.g. via `Attribute::get(context, "less-precise-fpmad", "false")`. The full picture is then something like:

```
LLVMContext c = ...
Function* f = ...
Attribute attr = Attribute::get(c, "less-precise-fpmad", "false");
f.addAttributes(0, AttributeSet::get(c, AttributeSet::FunctionIndex, attr));
```

Comment: Unfortunately - `error: no matching function for call to 'llvm::AttributeSet::get(llvm::LLVMContext&, int, llvm::Attribute&)'`

Comment: @kpdev I haven't tried the code myself, but I see there's `AttributeSet::get(LLVMContext &C, unsigned Index, AttrBuilder &B)`, and `AttrBuilder` has the implicit constructor `AttrBuilder(const Attribute &A)`, so it *should* work... you can try to create the `AttrBuilder` manually, though it should behave the same.

Comment: I added AttrBuilder, now I get next: `define "less-precise-fpmad"="false" void @main() #0` and `attributes #0 = { nounwind uwtable }`. Why it is added to define, but not to attributes under the function?

Comment: @kpdev I used the wrong index in my snippet above; I edited my answer to fix it.